# Intersection of convex spaces in R

Tags: r, intersection

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(C1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6), C2 = c(3.5, 3, 
2.5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5), C3 = c(6.5, 8, 9, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The first column is an index. The first observation is characterised by 1 point, the second by 2 points.

I need to make the intersection of all combinations of observations, one way. The result creates a new dataframe with a new index, with again some observations that are characterised by 2 rows/points: 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 3-4, 3-5, 3-6, 4-5, 4-6, 5-6:

```
df2 = structure(list(C1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6,7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 15), C2 = c(3,2,3,3,2,3.5,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,3), C3 = c(6.5,5,6.5,3,4,6,5,7,4,3,6,5,3,4,5,4,3,6,4,3)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                         -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

where 3 in the first column is the new observation created by intersecting the 2 former.

I though I could use `pmin` in each row but it does not work. Can somenone tackle this?
[image: graph representation]

Comment: If you put the points on a 2 axis graph it becomes clearer of what exactly is this intersection. We have spaces that is the area between the point and the axis. The intersection is the point for which 1 and 2 have an area in common. Is it clearer?

Comment: I have added more points

Comment: Not clear to me...you have two points for index `2`.. how do you handle that?

Comment: Is it better with the graph I added in the question? 1 and 2 are inverted on the graph.

Comment: Why 3 and not 2 ? as it intersect with the other (2;9) here as well.

Comment: On the graph, 3 is what 1 and 2 have in common, right?

Comment: I am only looking for a rule to select the correct point. The combination part has no importance

Comment: On the graph there's two 1, how do you choose the correct one ? Coding the rule is one thing, but if you don't have the rule and can not express it in plain english we won't be able to help you...

Comment: That means that observation 1 is defined by 2 points. Both are correct. Point 3 represents the common area, the intersection, between the area created by the points of obs 1 and those of obs 2. Is that clearer?

Comment: I have added the complete dataframe containing the expected output

Comment: Sorry, but that's still not clear, please [edit] your question to explain the logic, for exemple I've point 1 as coordinates 5,6 and point 2 at coordinates 2,3 should the result be 2,3 or null as there's no intersection of the "borders" of the area ? Something else which is unclear is as you have two observations with id 2, what the result from intersection of 1 with 2 should be, i.e: why is it 3 and not 2.5 ?

Comment: And why are there duplicate ids in the resulting dataframe ?

Comment: I have updated my question, which seems to be way too confusing, to another one -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/59336288/11849538

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the code is the thing you want, where `cummin()` is used

```
df2 <- cbind(df[1],cummin(df[-1]))
> df2
  C1  C2  C3
1  1 3.5 6.5
2  2 3.0 6.5
3  2 2.5 6.5
4  3 2.0 5.0
5  4 2.0 5.0
6  5 2.0 4.0
7  5 2.0 3.0
8  6 2.0 3.0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6), C2 = c(3.5, 3, 
2.5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5), C3 = c(6.5, 8, 9, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what it does. I only need the intersection like it is on the picture. For example 1 and 2 together should be ```(3,6.5)```

Comment: @Simon then you can see at the row 2 of `df2`, the result is `(3,6.5)`, which is a cumulative result after dealing with row 1 and 2 in `df1`. The idea here is to hold the lower values when iterating by rows

Comment: Ah okay! And what about the other rows? I don't really understand what it does

Comment: @Simon  am not very clear if I understand your goal in a right way...For the row 3 of `df2`, it means it will keep the lower value 3 in `C2` from df, but skip the value 9 in C3, since it is higher than the existing value 6 in row 2 of `df2`....do you understand what I mean?

Comment: if 1 is also characterised by a second row: ```(1,4,6)``` then it does not work since it will take ```6``` instead of ```6.5```

Comment: you are correct, but if the data is slightly different, the ```cummin()``` function does not work

Comment: @Simon could you give an example that it fails? I want to have a look at it

Comment: Thanks! try with this as df: ```structure(list(C1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6), C2 = c(3.5, 3, 
2.5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5), C3 = c(6.5, 8, 9, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))```

Comment: @Simon So what is the expected results for this `df`? I strongly recommend you add desired output in your post, otherwise what others can do is just to "guess" your expectation....

Comment: I have added df2 which is the full expected output. Thank you

Comment: @Simon I feel confused about `df2`: Why there are two `4`s in `C1`? How the duplicates in `df` are dealt with during all combinations as you said? For example, observation 2 in `df` has `(2,3,8)` and `(2,2.5,9)`, but how do they have combination with the observation 1 `(1,3,6.5)`? I did not see the intersection in between `(1,3,6.5)` and `(2,2.5,9)` from `df2`.....

Comment: I have updated this question, which seems too confusing, to another one -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/59336288/11849538