# Intersection of 2 polyhedra using intersectn() R

Tags: r, computational-geometry, intersection, convex-hull

I have 2 polyhedra generated by the following extreme points:

```
df1 = structure(c(3, 5, 8, 6), .Dim = c(2L, 2L))
df2 = structure(c(2, 4, 9, 7), .Dim = c(2L, 2L))
```

Those points, taken as constraint inequalities, create a space. I would like to select the hull formed by the intersection of those 2 polyhedra.

The use of the function `intersectn()` from the `geometry` package, but I get the following error.

```
Error in convhulln(ps1, "n FA") : 
  Received error code 1 from qhull. Qhull error:
QH6214 qhull input error: not enough points(2) to construct initial simplex (need 3)

While executing:  | qhull n FA  Qt
Options selected for Qhull 2015.2.r 2016/01/18:
  run-id 2112210196  normals  FArea-total  Qtriangulate  _pre-merge
  _zero-centrum
```

Any idea why I am getting this error? The following example works.

```
ps1 <- rbox(0, C=0.5)
ps2 <- rbox(0, C=0.5) + 0.5
out <- intersectn(ps1, ps2)
```

Comment: Could you explain how you get `ps1` and `ps2`?

Comment: They come from the example proposed in the package documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geometry/geometry.pdf

Comment: I don't see where. And I don't see how you could get a polyhedron from only two inequality constraints.

Comment: there is a function called ``ìntersectn()``` on page 20. Also, in my example this is a simplified example in 2 dimensions, for easier verification.

Comment: You mean you do `intersectn(df1, df2)`? `df1` and `df2` have two points only, you need at least three to define a polyhedron.

Comment: So I cannot, using this package, find the intersection of a plan and an area, or of 2 areas like in my example?

Comment: No you can't. What is the first inequality constraint of `df1`, is it `3x + 8y > 0` ?

Comment: It creates a step frontier: ```x<=3, y<=8 AND x<=5, y<=6```

Comment: I understant now why 3 points are needed. There is a free disposability assumption, which means that the hull is the area between the x and y axes and the points, any way to overcome this?

Comment: So `df1` defines an infinite rectangle : `x < 3, y < 6` (this is the intersection of the infinite rectangles `x < 3, y < 8` and `x < 5, y < 6`. Also `df2` defines an infinite rectangle. Both are open in the bottom-left direction. And what do you want ? The intersection of `df1` and `df2` is an infinite rectangle as well, you want the coordinates of its corner ?

Comment: precisely, excepted that df1 is the union of the infinite rectangles

Comment: and that the data that I will be using has 5 dimensions

Comment: The union is not a convex region. I'm not aware of any R package which can deal with that.

Comment: and what about the intersection of such rectangles(objects of higher dimension)? I could just implement an && to make it work

Comment: To get the (convex) intersection of regions defined by a set of linear inequalities, you can use the `rcdd` package or the `vertexenum` package.

Comment: I only need the extreme points... Can any of those packages can do this?

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what they do. See [here](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/integralPolyhedron.html) for an example of `rcdd` and `vertexenum`.

Comment: If you are familiar with those packages, can you maybe elaborate on my example? I don't really figure out how I can use them